# Grep command - Text processing

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a links.txt. I need this output.

links.txt:

```
http://www.google.com/test
https://bing.com/web2
www.yahoo.com/link/link2
```

output.txt

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/test" target="_blank">http://www.google.com/test</a>
<a href="https://bing.com/web2" target="_blank">https://bing.com/web2</a>
<a href="www.yahoo.com/link/link2" target="_blank">www.yahoo.com/link/link2</a>
```

Comment: Use sed.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is various ways, but I'll use the below

`for i in $(cat links.txt); do echo "<a href=\"$i\" target=\"_blank\">$i</a>"; done`